# Not able to delete 'generated' folder in Magento Cloud

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, cloud

We are using Magento Cloud Enterprise and using the Magento Version 2.2.

We are not able to delete the `generated/` folder, has anybody else faced this issue before?

<sub>*From comments:*</sub>
We tried deleting inside generated, yet we couldn't delete the contents, we are getting a "Read-only Filesystem" error.

Comment: Can you please let us know, what method you are following to delete it e.g. manually or CLI and what message you are getting while deleting it?

Comment: Magento Cloud uses a read only file system. Are you trying to deleted the `generated` folder itself (should not be possible)? Did you try deleting stuff inside `generated/*` (should be possible)?

Comment: As @7ochem suggesting, try deleting the contents inside.

Comment: Thank you Guys, we tried deleting it inside generated , yet we couldn't delete the contents, we are getting , 'Read-only Filesystem' Error

Comment: Aha, that's right. The generated folder is filled (generated) during the build process and is part of the write protected files. You should trigger a new build to re-generate the `generated/` folder

Comment: @RichardValsalan were you able to solve this?

Comment: @7ochem , we still seem to have the issue even after trying the recommended method

Answer (score 3):

Magento Cloud Enterprise files are locked within a read-only filesystem, with the exception of several files that should be writable by Magento 2 at runtime (logs, error reports, caches [if not in Redis]).

Also the `generated/` folder and the `pub/static/` folder and their content are fully write protected. Your website should run in production mode and all generated code and assets should not change in between builds.

The only way to re-generate (and thus clear) what's in the `generated/` folder is to trigger a new build which will compile the files (running `setup:di:compile`).

Comment: We actually, tried this, but it seems not to be working :(

Comment: How did you trigger it to build?

Comment: Hi @RichardValsalan Did you get any solutions?

Comment: Hi @RajanSoni ya I got a fix for ths... I raise a ticket in Magento cloud and they gave permission to my user account to delete and regenerate when required